# Linux - some way to keep a live-updating log file open in terminal?

Tags: linux, logging

This must've been done before: I want to keep a log file open in terminal so I can monitor updates to it as they occur.  My searches are coming up with everything but this situation... I must be missing some terminology or something key, because people do this all the time inside of other programs (NetBeans, or rails server, for example).

Comment: Ah, I've found it. `tail -f myfile.log`.  That does it nicely.  I love linux.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try with:

```
tail -f your.log
```

where `-f` stands for *follow*.

Comment: As you may need syntax highlight, `multitail` is handy i.e. 
**multitail -f your.log** ref. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8419/17671

Comment: Or even better is `grc` i.e. **grc tail -f your.log**
ref. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21962/17671

Answer (score 10):

Another way:

> watch tail -n20 your.log

OK, kind of a silly use of `watch` - but you might find the `watch` command useful for other things.

Comment: The `watch` option is better for files that are going to be renamed/removed and recreated (either by normal operation or by something like logrotate) during the time you are watching, otherwise `tail -f` is more efficient.

Comment: @David: `tail -F` handles that.

Comment: @grawity: Thanks, you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to @cYrus's answer is:

```
less +F file.log
```

The benefit is that `less` can also truncate long lines for you with the `-S` flag, preventing them from wrapping around the terminal screen while allowing you to scroll left/right. Instead of piping `tail -f file.log` through `cut` or something similar, you can just:

```
less -S +F file.log
```